# How to write generic IEnumerable<SelectListItem> extension method

Tags: c#, generics, extension-methods

I'm fairly new (ok, REALLy new) to generics but I love the idea of them.  I am going to be having a few drop-down lists on a view and I'd like a generic way to take a list of objects and convert it to a list of `SelectListItems`

What I have now:

```
public static IEnumerable<SelectListItem> ToSelectListItems(
     this IEnumerable<SpecificObject> items, long selectedId)
    {
        return
            items.OrderBy(item => item.Name)
            .Select(item =>
                    new SelectListItem
                    {
                        Selected = (item.Id == selectedId),
                        Text = item.Name,
                        Value = item.Id.ToString()
                    });
    }
```

Trouble is, I'd need to repeat that code for each drop-down as the objects have different fields that represent the `Text` property of the `SelectListItem`

Here is what I'd like to accomplish:

```
public static IEnumerable<SelectListItem> ToSelectListItem<T>(this IEnumerable<T> items, string key, string value, int SelectedId) {
    // I really have no idea how to proceed from here :(
}
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Well, you could do something like this:

```
public static IEnumerable<SelectListItem> ToSelectListItems(
     this IEnumerable<T> items, 
     Func<T,string> nameSelector, 
     Func<T,string> valueSelector, 
     Func<T,bool> selected)
{
     return items.OrderBy(item => nameSelector(item))
            .Select(item =>
                    new SelectListItem
                    {
                        Selected = selected(item),
                        Text = nameSelector(item),
                        Value = valueSelector(item)
                    });
}
```

Comment: Cancel that, had to do ToSelectListItems<T> :)

Comment: How would I call this and, particularly use the 'selected' delegate?

Answer (score 8):

You could pass in delegates to do the comparisons, and property retrieval.  Something like this:

```
public static IEnumerable<SelectListItem> ToSelectListItem<T>(this IEnumerable<T> items, 
    int selectedId, Func<T,int> getId, Func<T, string> getName, 
    Func<T, string> getText, Func<T, string> getValue)
{
    return
        items.OrderBy(item => getName(item))
        .Select(item =>
                new SelectListItem
                {
                    Selected = (getId(item) == selectedId),
                    Text = getText(item),
                    Value = getValue(item)
                });
}
```

Then you would use it like so:

```
var selected = specificObjects.ToSelectListItem(10, s => s.Id, s=> s.Name, s => s.Name, s => s.Id.ToString());
```

Comment: You'd also need a getName delegate (per Bruno's answer) -- the item.Name reference in the OrderBy clause currently won't compile.

Comment: Hmm, I want to mark both this and the next questions as answers :). Both are exactly what I'm looking for!

Answer (score 3):

In order for this to work as written, your type `T` will need to implement some interface which provides `Name` and `Id` properties:

```
 public interface ISelectable
 {
     string Name { get; }
     int Id { get; }
 }
```

With this in place, you can do:

```
public static IEnumerable<SelectListItem> ToSelectListItems<T>(this IEnumerable<T> items, long selectedId) 
     where T : ISelectable
{
    return
        items.OrderBy(item => item.Name)
        .Select(item =>
                new SelectListItem
                {
                    Selected = (item.Id == selectedId),
                    Text = item.Name,
                    Value = item.Id.ToString()
                });
}
```

This is required in order to use the `Name` and `Id` properties within your extension method...  You could, instead, provide a different means of receiving these (ie: passing delegates), but that may or may not increase the maintenance cost in your scenario.

Comment: Friend, with this method, how I would use it ? Looks cleaner than other answers. Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

//You need to use reflection to get the value of

```
   public static IEnumerable<SelectListItem> GetListItems<T> 
     (this IEnumerable<T> items, int selectedVal)
    {
        return from item in items
               select new SelectListItem
               {
                   Text =item.GetPropValue("Name"),
                    Value = item.GetPropValue("Id"),
                     Selected = 
                item.GetPropValue("Id").Equals(selectedVal.ToString())
               };
    }

    public static string GetPropValue<T> (this T item,string refName)
    {

        return 
           item.GetType().GetProperty(refName).GetValue(item).ToString();
    }
```